# How to provide argument to storage call in subxt?

Tags: rust, subxt, scale-codec, scale

In polkadotjs I have following code:

```
const opts = [{"UniqueIdenfier1":[0,"challengeprofile"]}]
let data = api.query.templateModule.periodName(
            ...opts,
            queryResHandler
          )
```

I want to convert it to rust subtxt:

```
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "./artifacts/metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}

let client = subxt::client::OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("ws://127.0.0.1:9944")
                        .await
                        .unwrap();
                
let period = polkadot::storage().template_module().period_name(&opts);
```

opt is an SumTreeName enum in substrate:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Clone, Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub enum SumTreeName {
    UniqueIdenfier1 { citizen_id: u128, name: Vec<u8>}
}
```

How to convert opts in rust format?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by importing `SumTreeName`

```
 #[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "./artifacts/metadata.scale")]
 pub mod polkadot {}


 let client = subxt::client::OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url("ws://127.0.0.1:9944")
                        .await
                        .unwrap();
 let key = polkadot::runtime_types::sortition_sum_game::types::SumTreeName::UniqueIdenfier1 {
                    citizen_id: 0,
                    name: "challengeprofile".as_bytes().to_vec(),
                };
 let period = polkadot::storage().template_module().period_name(&key);
```